# Convert IMAGE function to real image and save in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I used IMAGE function in Google Sheets to display image from url in another cell.

Is there anyway I can convert it into real images (not function) and save it into cell, so that I can open it in Excel when I download?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Insert -> Image -> Insert an image in the cell`

[image: Description image]

Comment: I have hundreds of row, cannot do this manually

Comment: Well it either that, or you'll have to use VBA code to transform the URL in excel to actual image. You might want to look at [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/convert-image-url-to-actual-image-in-excel/m-p/309020)